# Polygons shifted after random clicking

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I was following Blender Guru's tutorial when I accidentally went into layout mode. I didn't realise this and clicked a load of random things and this happened:
[image]

Can it be fixed or do I need to start again?

Comment: `Crtl`+`Z`... ?

Comment: maybe you've enabled the snap option?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a descriptive title that reflects the content of your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the vertices back where you want them in Edit mode. Looks like they’ve been moved only in the X direction so should be simple enough to G (grab), X (in X axis only), drag them back. There aren’t many so shouldn’t take long to put them back.

It’s difficult to give more precise instructions without knowing about what it is you did to mess them up.